# WPF - How to get current secondary screen's width if there are more than one secondary screen?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, avalondock

I am working on a wpf application which runs on multiscreen system (6 screens). My requirement is that when I drag a window from primary monitor to secondary monitor, it should be able to get the width of secondary monitor.

I tried following:

1. "SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth"
    It always gives primary Screen's width.
2. "System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens"
     If there are more than one screen how would I get the current secondary screen width?

Note: I am using AvalonDock for docking/floating functionality.

Comment: Can you not maximize the secondary window after dropping it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I can maximize the window on secondary monitor but I need to get the screen width of the secondary monitor to set the width of some controls in the window.

Comment: Its a bit urgent for me. It will be highly appreciated if anyone can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this issue?